# ODBC Connection Dropping Frequently

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

Not sure what is going on....

MS Access front end (on Win7 and 10 PCs)
MySQL on DiskStation (MariaDB) back end.
Connection is through ODBC 5.3.

All was perfect and great until one day I lost internet service for about 2 hours.  Once back up and running, we had a new dynamic IP.  No problem.  I changed the ODBC connection to the new IP and we're back up and running.

Then, a short time later, I start getting ODBC connection errors.  Either "connection failed" or "gone away".  Sometimes once a day, sometimes all machines (5 connections) randomly, many times throughout the day.

Sometimes if I just close and restart Access, the connection will enable.  Sometimes it won't.  Other times, I will "test" the ODBC driver and the first time it will fail, and the second time it will say "success", then all is well again.

Checked global wait timeout and it's set to 28800.

Since users connect both inside and outside of our LAN, the driver is set to our local IP, and then my Linksys router port forward 3806 to the internal IP of the DiskStation.  Again, until Rogers dropped service and I was forced to use a different IP, all was well in our little network world.

Can anyone shed some light?  Keep in mind, I am limited to my tech knowledge.

Comment: Because this is not a programming question I am voting to migrate to [DBA StackExchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) but [ServerFault SE](https://serverfault.com/) could work too as this involves your network setup. Try asking there.

Comment: OK Thanks... will do.